# Tabs Navigation is not working by clicking on Next/save button in Protractor

Tags: protractor, angular8

**this is the code for button Next/save button**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHHnr.png)

```
<a href="javascript:;"  class="btn btn-continue float-right w-18" id="formNext" (click)="search()">Next / Save</a>
```

**I used below code to click on next/save button using Protractor**

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(await element(by.id('formNext')).perform();
 await element(by.id('formNext)).click();
```

Comment: Please describe your issue in little more detail. What is the error happening or did you face any exception? Also Protractor is not a good choice since it is not being actively maintained.

Comment: @demouser123 Thanks for reply, i'm not getting any error or exception , but click event is not working there, it hover on button and click on it but navigate to next page is not happening can you refere image i attached

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sjlc3d     refer this image , my UI i need to navigate from search form to ground services tab , it would active when click on next/save button

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence of performing operations is not correct. Try this

```
let nextbtn = $('#formNext');
await browser.actions().mouseMove(nextbtn).click().perform();
```

In actions , you first perform whatever action you need to perform on the element `(click, doublclick etc.)` and then append it with `perform()`

Comment: i tried above it is not navigate to next tab , remains in same page

Comment: Have you added a delay like `browser.sleep(10000)` to see if this works